# How to adjust the mouse position after rotating an object?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an eye that follows cursor movement.
I got the horizontal and vertical coordinate of the mouse and the browser width and height. 
Everything works perfectly. Except that I used `rotate(45 deg)` on the design of the eye so now the ball is not moving in the right position.

I was thinking about a math equation that finds the distance between the old and new coords, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Here is the full code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Mr_MeS/3ym6kuec/3/

so this is the .eye where its rotated

```
.eye {
    width: 37.5px;
    height: 37.5px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
    border-radius: 75% 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ball {
    width: 7.5px;
    height: 7.5px;
    background: #222f3e;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #576574;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

and here is the JS that does the work and needs to be edited.

```
var balls = document.getElementsByClassName("ball");
document.onmousemove = function () {

    var x = event.clientX * 100 / window.innerWidth + "%";
    var y = event.clientY * 100 / window.innerHeight + "%";
    //event.clientX => get the horizontal coordinate of the mouse
    //event.clientY => get the Vertical coordinate of the mouse
    //window.innerWidth => get the browser width
    //window.innerHeight => get the browser height


    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        balls[0].style.left = x;
        balls[0].style.top = y;
        balls[0].style.transform = "translate(-" + x + ",-" + y + ")";
    }
}
```

Now, if I remove the rotation from the .eye, it works perfectly, expect that the whole shape doesn't look to be in position.

If I keep the 45deg rotation, the shape is good, but the ball moves wrongly.

Comment: Or maybe a pseudo element (::after) that is rotated? Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to put the eye-background (the white part that needs to rotate 45 degrees) into a div (or pseudo-element) that's inside the .eye element. In that way you don't need to rotate the container element, so the coordination of the ball element stays the same.

Another point, why are you using that for-loop? I think running the code once will be sufficient :)

---

EDIT: I've been playing around with your example a bit and fixed it. What happens is that if you rotate an element, the direction in which things will transform (and top/left positioning) will also change. So moving the element 10px to the left, will go 10px to the left, under a 45 degree angle, because it's rotated 45 degrees.

What I did now was to put an element (.inner) inside the eye div, which I gave a counter-rotation of -45 degrees. In this way, the container element of the ball has the correct orientation again, which fixes the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/bxprjvgL/

HTML:

```
<div class="eye">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="shut"><span></span></div>
      <div class="ball"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! i know if i was an experienced programmer, i would get it. but i am not :). here is what i did to the html part. i hope you can help me! thank you!  https://jsfiddle.net/Mr_MeS/7coq9612/

Comment: No problem :) Knowing what happens is important to find bugs and solutions. I've been playing around with your example for a bit and changed my answer above with the explanation.

Comment: You are awesome!!! Never thought of counter-rotation. i was diving deep into sin and cos of an angle haha. thank you so much :)